# Select as target one instance of an object

Tags: c#

is there someting like that in c#?

```
with(myPoint)
{
    X=10;
    Y=10;
}
```

that is equivalent to

```
myPoint.X=10;
myPoint.Y=10;
```

Comment: there are stucts and classes. i suggest you use class as starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
myPoint = new Point() { X = 10, Y = 10 };
```

Just replace `Point` with the point class of your choosing. However, some only work using the constructor:

```
myPoint = new Point(10, 10);
```

Comment: to the point struct it works very well but how can i do this with the grapycs?

Comment: @Thiago I tried to answer your original question. However, this smells like it might be a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/305801).